# Iterating to vector after conversion from array

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

```cpp
int arr[6] = {1, 4, 20, 3, 10, 5};

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < N; j++) { 
       //some stuff...
    } 
}

//Above code is iterating twice to array.
```

After converting array to vector. I have to apply same logic in vector. 
Please guide how can I iterate in `std::vector`.

Comment: `std::vector` has `operator[]`

Comment: what did you try for vector that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to operate on the elements of `std::vector<int>` and whether you need the index information. E.g., if you want to iterate over `std::vector<int> v` and want to change the elements, you could use

```
for( auto& val : v )
{
    val = 0;
}
```

If you do not change the elements, use

```
for( const auto& val : v )
{
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

If you need index information, use the index operator []

```
std::size_t size = v.size();

for( std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
    v[i] = i;
}
```

Now, if you (really?) want to use `std::vector<int>` to store your data but need to be fast in a specific loop, maybe you should prefer something like

```
int* data = v.data();
std::size_t size = v.size();

for( std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i, ++data )
{
    *data = i;
}
```